# How to prevent users from uploading the same file twice WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my WordPress website, the users are uploading the same image file twice and trice, So my site's Disk Space exceeding.

**Is there any option to prevent users to upload the same image file again and again.?**

Comment: if they chnage the file name you can't stop this. but you can put some validation for restrict them to limited number of image upload according to your functionality.

Comment: Share the code and link where you want this.

Comment: @RajkumarGour they are not changing the file name they are uploading the same picture again and again. Can you please help me to add the validation.?

Comment: @TechnoDeviser www.ceylontravellerlk.com this is my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Instead of adding any validation I added following filter hook which replaces the image, if image with same name already exists. Add this code to your **functions.php** file

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'replace_image_if_same_exists', 10, 1 );

function replace_image_if_same_exists( $name ) 
{
  $args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'attachment',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array( 
                'key' => '_wp_attached_file',
                'value' => $name,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
  );
  $attachments_to_remove = get_posts( $args );

  foreach( $attachments_to_remove as $attach )
    wp_delete_attachment( $attach->ID, true );

 return $name;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This solution may not be ideal if two very different images have the same file name. You're potentially overwriting someone else's file based on a very weak criteria.

Comment: @JustinR.yeah thats true but how do we fix this.?

Comment: @JustinR. this may not be the ideal solution. Trying to get a better solution

Comment: As a suggestion, you could implement an image comparison library (such as ImageMagick) and utilize that in your code.

Comment: @JustinR , I will check that out.